# why core dump file is generated only in specific dir in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gdb, coredump

i have wrriten a sample c program to generate core dump. but this generates core dump only when executed in specific dir /var/crash however when executed in other dir it does not generate. why? I am using ubuntu-20.

when i run program in /var/crash

```
/var/crash>./a.out 
Caught signal 11, generating core dump...
Aborted (core dumped)

/var/crash>ls /var/crash
_var_crash_a.out.1000.crash  a.out
/var/crash>
```

when i run in my home dir no core file generated

```
/home/ubuntu>./a.out 
Caught signal 11, generating core dump...
Aborted (core dumped)
/home/ubuntu>
/home/ubuntu>ls
a.out                           ----> no core dump file generated
/home/ubuntu>
```

ulimit value

/home/ubuntu>ulimit -c unlimited

my core dump generator code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void crash_handler(int sig) {
  printf("Caught signal %d, generating core dump...\n", sig);
  fflush(stdout);
  abort();
}

int main() {
  struct sigaction sa;
  sa.sa_handler = crash_handler;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

  if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("sigaction");
    exit(1);
  }

  int* p = NULL;
  *p = 42;

  return 0;
}
```

core pattern output

```
/home/ubuntu>cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E
/home/ubuntu>
```

Comment: Look at the output of `cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`. You probably have it configured to put dumps under `/var/crash`. [Additional reading](https://linuxhint.com/setting-linux-core-dump-location/).

Comment: The classic pattern is just `core` without a directory, which produces a core file in the current dir, which is what you probably were expecting.

Comment: hi @teapot418 yes i am expecting it to be in my current dir or anywhere but it must be generated. but why crash is generated only when i run in /var/crash not in my home or other dir? i have added the output of cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern in my main thread it has nothing special. plz have a look

Comment: apport is likely putting core dumps into /var/crash all the time, regardless of the directory the program crashes in. If you want to change that, asking in https://askubuntu.com is recommended.

Comment: hi @MarkPlotnick and  i do not see any file in /var/crash/ when my core generator code is in home dir and executed from there.   i see core file only when i keep my core genrator bin file in /var/crash dir. is it not streng per core_pattern config....core must be saved in /var/crash  issresptive of your bin code location

Answer (score 0):

> no core dump file generated

You are likely mistaken -- the message says that `core` *was* generated.

It just wasn't generated in the current directory, due to `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`, as other commenters have mentioned.

Comment: I think you did not understand my issue clearly.  core file gets generaed in /var/crash when i keep my cresh gen bin file in this dir and run from there. if the bin file is in home dir and executed there then it does not save file in /var/crash  even does not create at all. per the documentation of core_pattern  core file must be in /var/crash in all situation s irrespective of where the bin is executed

Comment: @myquest6sh The commands you show: `/home/ubuntu>ls`  does _not_ demonstrate what you described. You need to show the output from `/home/ubuntu>ls /var/crash`.

Comment: @Employer Russian i have just updated the main thread with ls /var/crash output

Comment: @myquest6sh Don't update the "main thread". Edit your question instead.